# Disable Jquery checkbox click in multiselect dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have jquery multiselect dropdown in which there is checkbox click event trigger on clicking of checkbox.

How can I avoid checkbox click trigger when checkbox is clicked

I need to give button and want to call function only when that button is clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can `return false` for checkbox click event. This will stop event bubbling ( `stopPropogation()` ) and prevent default action ( `preventDefault()` ) for click event like posting back to server.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('input:checkbox[name*=multiselect_]').click(function(){
  return false;
 });

});
```

Comment: where can i do that in jquery.ui.min.js file

Comment: no dont touch that file... instaed do this in your script file

Comment: http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/ is what i am using

Comment: do you mean you want to avoid checking the checkbox if they are clicked ??

Comment: return false avoids submission

Answer (score 0):

if you can provide markup then that would make your question more clear. but if there is a click event on the checkbox then what you should do is to prevent it.

```
$('checkbox').on('click',function(e){
 //prevent the event 
 e.preventDefault();

 });
```